# Tool to help breaking multitenant into a single tenant

Tags: oracle, etl, multi-tenant

Oracle 11.2.0.4

I've been tasked with breaking out a single customer from our multitenant system into a separate system. And the data will have to be continuously updated.  This is a large system with thousands of tables and unfortunately all foreign keys are not in place, the application maintains some level referential integrity (horrible, but in place well before me) AND the system doesn't have a tenant identifier at every level.

Essentially, the relationships between tables are often very complex.

In my mind, all this leads to the conclusion that effectively custom views or custom etl scripts will have to be created for every table.  "Management" thinks there must be some kind of tool to assist with this, defining rules, generating scripts, and such.

So, is anyone of aware of such a tool to assist with breaking a single tenant out of a multi tenant?  I know I'm being vague here, but its a vague issue and I keep getting asked if I've "found a tool yet"...which seems unlikely to me.

Comment: I feel your pain and suggest exporting all the data to a dev environment, deleting everyone else's data and spinning up a new instance.

Comment: To anyone tempted to downvote/close this question - this is not a "shopping-list" or "opinion-based" - it is a question about the **existence** of any tools which might perform this function and therefore IMHO, on-topic! How are you going to cope with reference tables? I would go with db links if they are rarely updated. Sounds like an interesting project - though I'm not sure if I'd like to be the one doing it! :-) +1 for an interesting question!

Comment: Coping with the reference tables is one of the huge challenges and one of the parts I'm struggling thinking of even a semi efficient solution for.

Comment: I suggest that even if there was a tool that could understand which tables/columns are metadata and which contain tenant data it would be an enterprise level tool with a six figure cost to licence and implement.

The next question you should ask management is when is the next tenant going to be detangled from the master or monolith application?

Comment: That's definitely part of the discussion actually - if this is something they want to 'offer' to costumers.  I can't go into details for privacy reasons...but a six figure tool if it enabled this to work smoothly, is acceptable.

Comment: @Vérace An answer to the question as stated ("is anyone aware") would be simply "yes" or "no" and not very useful as such. When transformed to a more useful "which tool?", it automatically becomes a "shopping list" question as defined in the closing options.

Comment: Its enormously useful if you don't know if such a thing even exists lol

Comment: I reread your question and have come to the conclusion that such a tool is **impossible** for your use case! If `all foreign keys are not in place` then no tool is going to be able to guess what they are! Take a look [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A34007+%22design+disasters%22+%22lewis%22+) at what a veteran SQL performance tuner and author (536 pages on (only) the **fundamentals** of the [Optimizer](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=jonathan+lewis+oracle+optimizer&ref=nb_sb_noss)) has to say about enforcing DRI in the app layer. You need to refactor before anything else!

Comment: There's no getting around that you're going to have to do a lot of work to determine what data belongs to this customer and what data belongs to other customers. You can use the foreign key metadata to help with this, but if there are keys missing then those tables will have to be analyzed "by hand".